# First, the page is rendered, and only then the data comes in, but the old data remains on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

The transition was made through react-router. I am trying to make the first project using Redux and I ran into the problem that my page is loading data that is not needed at the moment.

To be more specific, I have 2 classes in one form for selecting 1 of 3 components and index 1 is attached to each, 2 and 3. In the console you can see that when clicked, Redux picks up the data in the Store.

After selecting any component, the button for going to the next page becomes available. After switching to it, I would like to display the already entered data in the corner, but a default value has already been entered there. I came to the conclusion that the second page, which is not available until the user chose the option, it is rendered before the selection and is not updated after that, that's why the default hangs.

Maybe there is an option to prohibit rendering until the flag takes a different value or something like that?
[image]

The picture shows that in the last file the value 0 is immediately taken and does not change anymore.
my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Card,CardGroup,Button,Navbar,Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'
import A2 from '../assets/A2example.png'
import A3 from '../assets/A3example.png'
import A4 from '../assets/A4example.png'
import {BrowserRouter,  Route, Switch, Link, } from 'react-router-dom'
import ZakazPortretaSecond from '../pages/ZakazPortretaSecond';
import store from '../redux/store'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


class ZakazPortreta extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            choosen: 4
        }     
    }
        portretSize(a){
            this.setState({
                choosen: a
            })
            store.dispatch({
                type: 'SET_FORMAT_BY',
                payload: a,
            })
            console.log(store.getState())
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className = "ZakazDiv">
                <h2>Выберите желаемый размер портрета:A{this.state.choosen}</h2><br/>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls = "responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Link to="/ZakazPortretaSecond" >Далее</Link>
                </Navbar.Toggle>
                <CardGroup>
                    <Card>
                        <Card.Body className = "cards" onClick={()=> this.portretSize(4)}>
                            <Card.Title>А4</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">210×297 мм</Card.Subtitle>
                            <Card.Text>
                                <img src = {A4} width = "370" height = "550"/>
                            </Card.Text>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    <Card >
                        <Card.Body className = "cards" onClick={()=> this.portretSize(3)}>
                            <Card.Title>А3</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">297 x 420 мм</Card.Subtitle>
                            <Card.Text>
                            <img src = {A3} width = "370" height = "550"/>
                            </Card.Text>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    <Card >
                        <Card.Body className = "cards" onClick={()=> this.portretSize(2)}>
                            <Card.Title>А2</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted"> 420 x 594 мм</Card.Subtitle>
                            <Card.Text>
                            <img src = {A2} width = "370" height = "550"/>
                            </Card.Text>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </CardGroup>
                <BrowserRouter >
                    <div>
                        <Nav />
                        <Route path="/ZakazPortretaSecond" component={ZakazPortretaSecond} />
                    </div>
                    </BrowserRouter >
            </div>
        )
    }
    
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("Actual value",store.getState())
    return{
        format: state.format,
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ZakazPortreta)
```

and second file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import store from '../redux/store'

console.log("inside last file",store.getState())

class ZakazPortretaSecond extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className='textSecond text-center'>Вы выбрали:A{store.format}</h2> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ZakazPortretaSecond
```

Comment: `useSelector` or `connect` should refresh automatically with new data when the store state changes.  So something isn't right in your code. Please post a [mimimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: i am edit my question, try to learn it
connect doesn't work

Comment: connect don't refresh data in other pages, it's my problem @LindaPaiste

Comment: You are using a `Link` outside of a `BrowserRouter`.  Is this the only `BrowserRouter` in your app?  I'm not sure if this one is misplaced or an unnecessary duplicate.

Comment: How is this? https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-paper-sizes-p0rnr?file=/src/components/ZakazPortreta.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating the information separately on the page on load
Worked code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import store from '../redux/store'

console.log("inside last file",store.getState())
const refreshInf = () => {
    let formats = store.getState().format
    console.log(formats)
    return formats
}

class ZakazPortretaSecond extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div onLoad = {refreshInf()}>
                <h2 className='textSecond text-center'>Вы выбрали:A{refreshInf()}</h2> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ZakazPortretaSecond
```

function refreshInf on div has been refresh information in store!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working but this is not a great long-term solution.  You'll want to use either `connect` or the `useDispatch`/`useSelector` hooks.  I'll take a look at your code and see if I can figure out why you are having trouble.

Comment: I have other navigation menu in site, and my version suits me, it's little and inconsiderable  piece of site